# Implementing comparison operators in Bytecode using ASM

Tags: bytecode, java-bytecode-asm, jvm-bytecode

I'm working on a personal project of mine creating a simple language which is compiled to Java Bytecode. I'm using the ASM library version 7.3.1 but I've hit a problem with Frames that I can't quite figure out.

This is actually two questions rolled into one. I'm trying to implement simple comparison operators e.g. `>`, `<`, `>=` etc. These operators should return a boolean result obviously. I can't see a way of implementing this directly in Bytecode so I'm using using `FCMPG` to compare two floats that are already on the stack and then using `IFxx` to push either a `1` or `0` to the stack depending on which operator I'm generating code for.

For example here is my code for `>`:

```scala
val label = new Label()
mv.visitInsn(FCMPG)           // mv is my MethodVisitor, there are 2 Floats on the stack
mv.visitJumpInsn(IFGT, label)
mv.visitInsn(ICONST_1)
mv.visitLabel(label)
mv.visitInsn(ICONST_0)
```

Question 1: Is this the correct approach for implementing comparison operators or am I missing a simpler method?

Question 2: Running this code generates this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0
    at org.objectweb.asm.Frame.merge(Frame.java:1268)
    at org.objectweb.asm.Frame.merge(Frame.java:1244)
    at org.objectweb.asm.MethodWriter.computeAllFrames(MethodWriter.java:1610)
    at org.objectweb.asm.MethodWriter.visitMaxs(MethodWriter.java:1546)
    at compiler.codegen.default$$anon$1.generateConstructor(default.scala:138)
    at compiler.codegen.default$$anon$1.generateCode(default.scala:157)
    at compiler.codegen.default$$anon$1.generateCode(default.scala:21)
    at compiler.codegen.package$.generateCode(package.scala:21)
    at compiler.codegen.package$CodeGeneratorOp.generateCode(package.scala:17)
    at Main$.main(main.scala:27)
    at Main.main(main.scala)
```

I know this is to do with Frames but I don't really understand frames enough to know what I'm doing wrong. I've tried adding `mv.visitFrame(F_SAME, 0, null, 0, null)` after `visitLabel` but I get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Yes, this is the correct way to do it. I believe the actual Java compiler does something very similar.

2) You get a verification error because you forgot to add a jump to the end of the if block. If you look closely at your code, you'll see that when the jump isn't taken **both** branches are executed and you end up with both 0 and 1 on the stack, which leads to a verification error. You need to insect a second jump so only the constant you wish gets pushed to the stack in this case. It should be something like this:

```
val then_label = new Label()
val end_label = new Label()
mv.visitInsn(FCMPG)           // mv is my MethodVisitor, there are 2 Floats on the stack
mv.visitJumpInsn(IFGT, then_label)
mv.visitInsn(ICONST_1)
mv.visitGoto(end_label)
mv.visitLabel(then_label)
mv.visitInsn(ICONST_0)
mv.visitLabel(end_label)
```

Comment: That's it! Thanks @Antimoney